# Use workflow service with msmqIntegrationBinding

Tags: wcf, workflowservice, msmqintegrationbinding

I have been struggling with setting up a workflow service that uses a msmqIntegrationBinding. The problem I have now is that I always get this serialization exception *"System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: An error was encountered while deserializing the message. The message cannot be received. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An error occurred while deserializing an MSMQ message's XML body. The message cannot be received. Ensure that the service contract is decorated with appropriate [ServiceKnownType] attributes or the TargetSerializationTypes property is set on the MsmqIntegrationBindingElement."*

As far as I have understood is that the serialization helper cannot find any types to serialize the message to even though I am using the generic type *MsmqMessage<MyMessageType>* both in the service contract and in the workflow.

*MyMessageType* is generated from an .xsd with xsd.exe.

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED**
I did all settings for WCF (Action, ServiceKnownType...) on the contract (interface) instead of doing it in the workflow. When I moved it to the workflow everything started to work!!

Answer (score 1):

As a WCF beginner this had me a bit stumped. I had missed the `[ServiceKnownType]` attribute when going through a MSDN MSMQ [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx).

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(PurchaseOrder))]
public interface IOrderProcessor
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void SubmitPurchaseOrder(MsmqMessage<PurchaseOrder> msg);
}
```